# Installing Python 3.6.3 - "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" is missing from my Win8Pro64bit computer

Tags: python, powershell, installation

**OS**: Windows 8 64bit with the latest update.

**Objective**: Run Python.exe with Powershell as an administrator.

I've changed the path to include the script but when I try to open Python I get an error code. I receive the same error during the installation.

[api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from my computer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuVW3.png)

How would I go about resolving this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is usually caused by the missing Visual C++ Redistributable, which is a required dependency to install Python on Windows Computer.

To install Python successfully, download `Visual C++ Redistributable` from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and install it and Reboot the system.

After installing this, you would be able to install Python.

Link: [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: I've noticed that even if you install redist the error may persist for many possible reasons: 1- version uncompatibility (2015,2017...), 2- Missing Windows Update, 3- Uncompatible Windows version...etc.
The best way so far, is to install Anaconda (or Miniconda).